# TLorentz vector in Uproot 4

Tags: awkward-array

I try to use TLorentz vector in uproot4.
But I found that methods in "uproot_methods" module are now worked with Awkward High level array.

Error message  # -------------------------------------------->
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jwkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward/array/base.py", line 389, in _util_toarray
return cls.numpy.frombuffer(value, dtype=getattr(value, "dtype", defaultdtype)).reshape(getattr(value, "shape", -1))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Array'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "anal.py", line 19, in 
Electron_T2vec   = TVector2Array.from_polar(Electron_pt,Electron_phi)
File "/home/jwkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward/util.py", line 112, in func_wrapper
wrap, arrays = unwrap_jagged(cls, awkcls, _normalize_arrays(cls, arrays))
File "/home/jwkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward/util.py", line 84, in _normalize_arrays
arrays[i] = cls.awkward.util.toarray(arrays[i], cls.awkward.numpy.float64)
File "/home/jwkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward/util.py", line 32, in toarray
return awkward.array.base.AwkwardArray._util_toarray(value, defaultdtype, passthrough=passthrough)
File "/home/jwkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward/array/base.py", line 394, in _util_toarray
return cls.numpy.array(value, copy=False)
File "/home/jwkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward1/highlevel.py", line 1310, in **array**
return awkward1._connect._numpy.convert_to_array(self._layout, args, kwargs)
File "/home/jwkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward1/_connect/_numpy.py", line 16, in convert_to_array
out = awkward1.operations.convert.to_numpy(layout, allow_missing=False)
File "/home/jwkim/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awkward1/operations/convert.py", line 313, in to_numpy
return to_numpy(array.toRegularArray(), allow_missing=allow_missing)
ValueError: in ListOffsetArray64, cannot convert to RegularArray because subarray lengths are not regular
-------------------------------------------------->  ##

It seems that "uproot_method" only support the awkward.array.jagged.JaggedArray.
**Is there any other way to use the TLorentz vector in uproot4 (awkward high level array)?**

I'm trying to convert this uproot3 and awkward0 based code to uproot4 and awkward1 based code.
https://github.com/JW-corp/J.W_Analysis/blob/main/Uproot/anal.py

Thank youy!

Answer (score 0):

The `uproot-methods` package only works with Uproot 3.x and therefore Awkward Array 0.x. In the Uproot 4/Awkward 1 world, the methods for ROOT objects that `uproot-methods` once provided are now handled by Uproot itself (the "community contributed project" didn't work out, so this functionality is moving back into Uproot), except for Lorentz vectors.

The eventual home for Lorentz vector handling is the [vector](https://github.com/scikit-hep/vector) project, which I'll be contributing to in March. Here it is, almost March, and so that will be happening soon. (I have one last task before working on that.)

In the meantime, the excellent Coffea project has a module for Lorentz-vector handling: [coffea.nanoevents.methods.vector](https://coffeateam.github.io/coffea/modules/coffea.nanoevents.methods.vector.html). To get started with Lorentz vectors now, I recommend that.

(The standalone `vector` package would become Uproot's default vector handler, as in, if you read a TLorentzVector from a ROOT file, it will have `vector` methods automatically—when `vector` is finished, that is.)

Comment: Ok, I understand that the Loretnz vector with uproot4 will be added future.

Comment: Thank you very much!. I'm using Coffea Framework when I analyze the NanoAOD. Can I use the Coffea with general root files? ( ex. Delphes or ExROOTanalyaer in Madgraph )

Comment: You might need to construct the vectors manually if they're not coming from NanoEvents. How to do that is probably deeper in the documentation, or raise it as a Discussion on the Coffea GitHub page.